# reacquire contourf return value in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can get a object after the function contourf like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im = plt.contourf(np.random.rand(10,10))
```

however, is it possible to reacquire the object, im, like this:

```
plt.contourf(np.random.rand(10,10))
im = plt.gca().get_contourf?
```

Comment: No, you could only obtain the individual `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection` objects, not the `QuadContourSet` itself. But what is the problem of assigning the return value to a variable as in the first case? Because such questions are often a [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info), it would be better to ask about the actual problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. actually there is not complicated reason for this question. I just liked to know if there is any method to reach this result because sometime I forgot to assign the value to the command, contourf. I like to reacquire it and modify the cmap of this contourf. 

So maybe I should ask if any method to modify the cmap without assigning any value to contourf?

Comment: No, just don't forget to assign the contourf to a variable. But if you do, it's not that bad, you can just edit and rerun the code.